# arr.splice(begin, until) - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's my basic setup (javascript, of course):

```
var bookmark = {
    ...
        deleteBookmark: function(_id) {
            var oldbookmarks = this.readBookmarks();
            var begin = oldbookmarks.indexOf(_id);
            if (begin > -1) {
                var newbookmarks = oldbookmarks.splice(begin, 1);
                localStorageService.set('bookmarks', newbookmarks);
            }
        },
    ...
};
```

Note: this worked perfectly until today. Suddenly, `newbookmarks` isn't the difference, it's an array containing only the bookmark id from `_id`.

**Environment:**
*Browser:* Latest Chrome, Firefox
*Server:* Node 0.12.2 via Express
*Framework:* AngularJS, Yeoman, Angular-Fullstack Generator

Comment: It seems you misunderstood `splice`. The syntax is not `arr.splice(begin, until)`, it's `arr.splice(begin, numberOfItemsToRemove)`. Then it also accepts additional arguments which will be inserted in the array at that place. And as you discovered, it returns an array with the removed items.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wait. In the process of writing the question, I did some research and found out that the people who wrote the spec for this might have been idiots. It's because the splice method returns the deleted element from the array - meaning it's an operator, not a function.

The corrected usage from above would be:

```
var bookmark = {
    ...
        deleteBookmark: function(_id) {
            var oldbookmarks = this.readBookmarks();
            var begin = oldbookmarks.indexOf(_id);
            if (begin > -1) {
                oldbookmarks.splice(begin, 1);
                localStorageService.set('bookmarks', oldbookmarks);
            }
        },
    ...
};
```

Comment: Indeed, you answered your own question. :)

Comment: You conclusion is a non sequitur. `.splice()` is a method, not an operator.

Comment: @thomasfuchs: yes, sorry. it was one of those things; I spent so much time on writing it, I didn't want it to go to waste.

Comment: @Juhana, perhaps non-sequitor is not the right word; I should have said that the `splice()` method _acts_ like an operator, not _is_ an operator.

Comment: I don't understand how operators or functions have anything to do with it. Both can return/evaluate to anything at all.